# Обработка нажатия клавиш jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть функция, которая по клику мыши выделяет элемент (добавляет класс `selected`).

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

**Вопрос:** Как делать тоже самое, но только при зажатой клавише <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте для этого [Event.ctrlKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey).

Это свойство возвращает `true`, если клавиша <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> нажата во время события, и `false` - если не нажата.

```js
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  }
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что мне нужно!